# How to directly query SAP HANA via AWS Glue Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue, hana

I'm utilizing the [NGDBC driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.db.jdbc/ngdbc/2.14.10) (SAP HANA JDBC driver) with an AWS Glue Notebook. I'm using the following line once I include the JAR file to access data from SAP HANA in our environment.

```
df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("url", db_url).option("dbtable", "KNA1").option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()
```

In this example, it simply download the KNA1 table, but I have yet to see any documentation that tells me how to actually query the SAP HANA instance through these options. I attempted to use a "query" option, but that didn't seem like it was available via the JAR.

Am I to understand that I have to simply get entire tables, then query against the DataFrame? That seems expensive and not what I want to do. Maybe someone can provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

> df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("url", db_url).option("dbtable", **"(select name1 from kna1 where kunnr='1111') as name"**).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()

i.e. wrap the query into asterisks and provide an alias as [help suggests](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html).